# How do I remove the space between the list headings and the list items in latex?

Tags: white-space, bullets

```
\begin{rsection}{Project}
{ \bf Movie Recommender System}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item Implemented the collaborative filtering algorithm
\item performed exploratory data analysis
\end{itemize}
\end{rsection}
```

The output:

**Movie Recommender System**

- Implemented the collaborative filtering algorithm
- Performed exploratory data analysis

I want to reduce space between "Movie Recommender System" and the bullet points.

Comment: you are asking about some non standard environment `rsection` without giving any clue how it is defined. Note also `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993.

Comment: you don't say but it seems you are defining the `itemize` list with the `enumitem` package, in which case you may want `nosep` rather than `noitemsep`

Comment: There's no change whether I use noitemsep or nosep. And yes I have used enumitem.

Comment: if you want someone to debug your code then you need to provide an example, which should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` so we can run it. Perhaps `rsection` sets up a non standard list layout, but as you have given no indication how it is defined, it is impossible even to guess an answer.